# Is it possible to determine the SSL/TLS version of a Perl Mason Request?

Tags: perl, ssl, https, mason

Is there some way to retrieve the TLS version used for a Perl Mason Request?

Comment: Is the request you're talking about being sent or received by the Mason application?

Comment: received.  In this scenario, Perl Mason is a webserver, and wants to know what TLS version the browser used on the request.

Answer (score 4):

`$m->req->{env}{'psgix.io'}->`[`get_sslversion`](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket::SSL#get_sslversion%28%29)

Comment: Thanks!  But http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/PSGI-1.102/PSGI/Extensions.pod  "psgix.io: The raw IO socket to access the client connection to do low-level socket operations. This is only available in PSGI servers that run as an HTTP server, and should be used when (and only when) you want to jailbreak out of PSGI abstraction, to implement protocols over HTTP such as BOSH or WebSocket."  It seems like we don't have access to the socket connection in the Perl/Mason thread.

Comment: Not having access and your refusal to access are two different things.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mason but from the referenced documentation it looks like that `$m->req->{env}{'psgix.io'}` is the socket object, i.e. an `IO::Socket::SSL` object in this case. But `{*sslsock}{_SSL_arguments}{SSL_version}` does not give the SSL version for the current socket. It instead gives the `SSL_version` argument used to create the socket, i.e. something like `SSLv23:!SSLv3`. Also, accessing undocumented internal parts of the `IO::Socket::SSL` is not nice :).  Anyway, to get the actually used protocol version for the socket use `$sslsock->get_sslversion`.